# Cannot list all the sub-directories in Linux using c#

Tags: c#

This is the code that I'm trying to execute:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class TutorialClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo search_path = new DirectoryInfo(@"/home/mark");
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo("PixmapComposite.cs");

        DirectoryInfo dir_result = FindFile(search_path, file);

        if (dir_result == null)
            Console.WriteLine("File not found");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("The directory path is: {0}", dir_result.FullName);
    }

    public static DirectoryInfo FindFile(DirectoryInfo dir, FileInfo file_name)
    {
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", file.Name);
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (file.Name == file_name.Name)
            {
                return file.Directory;
            }
            else
            {
                // Search the remaining directories
                Console.WriteLine("Master dir: {0}", dir.FullName);
                DirectoryInfo[] sub_dir = dir.GetDirectories();
                foreach (DirectoryInfo current_dir in sub_dir)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Dir: {0}", current_dir.FullName);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    return FindFile(current_dir, file_name);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The directory that this program refers to mostly contains the following directory listing:

```
c#_code      Downloads           HelloWorld                   Public
c#_examples  eclipse             Music                        Templates
code         eclipse-workspace   packages-microsoft-prod.deb  tutprog
Desktop      eclipse-workspace2  Pictures                     tut_prog
Documents    examples.desktop    Projects                     Videos
```

The file namely, PixmapComposite.cs is in the c#_examples directory. This is the file that the program is looking for. However when I print out what directories are actually searched I get the following listing:

File: .ICEauthority

Master dir: /home/mark
Dir: /home/mark/.cache

File: event-sound-cache.tdb.3b78ab22329c4ff8b2de7f39f19853b8.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Master dir: /home/mark/.cache
Dir: /home/mark/.cache/.fr-M8r1wi

File not found

Comment: Your "search remaining directories" block should be *outside* the `foreach` loop, otherwise you are going to search all subdirectories for every file entry in every directory. This isn't necessarily the source of your problem, but it's an egregious performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are only searching sub-directories if you find a file entry that doesn't match what you are looking for. That means if you have a directory with no files in it (only directories) you won't search any of its sub-directories. Move the block that searches sub-directories outside of the `foreach` loop. Also, you need to let the sub-directory search continue on without returning as long as it hasn't found a directory with the target in it by checking for `null` before returning.

```
public static DirectoryInfo FindFile( DirectoryInfo dir, FileInfo file_name )
            {
                    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
                    foreach( FileInfo file in files) {
                        Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", file.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        if( file.Name == file_name.Name)
                        {
                             return file.Directory;
                        }
                    }
                    // Search the remaining directories
                    Console.WriteLine("Master dir: {0}", dir.FullName);
                    DirectoryInfo[] sub_dir = dir.GetDirectories();
                    foreach( DirectoryInfo current_dir in sub_dir) {
                         Console.WriteLine("Dir: {0}", current_dir.FullName);
                         Console.WriteLine();
                         var result = FindFile(current_dir, file_name );
                         if (result != null)
                             return result;
                    }
                    return null;
            }
```

Comment: I changed the code in-line with your comments and it worked. Awesome!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at code I wrote earlier this year to get files :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WriteFileNamesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();


        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details as to what this code is doing to help the user understand how you solution helps them.