# Error when searching for files in directory C#

Tags: c#, file, search, directory

I'm searching for files in my C# program using the following function:

```
        static string[] getFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
    {
        string[] searchPatterns = searchPattern.Split('|');
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            foreach (string sp in searchPatterns)
                files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path, sp, searchOption));
            files.Sort();
        } catch (Exception ex){ System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

        return files.ToArray();
    }
```

When I search for files I pass in the following code to my function:

```
var myDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

var files = getFiles(myDocuments, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Now when I execute the code I get the following error:

[image]

For some reason it's searching Documents/My Music instead of C:\Users\Test\Music. The error is occurring on Win7. I presume the cause of the problem is described in the following link (even tho I never upgraded my Windows): [Microsoft Document Changes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/930128/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-the-my-documents-my-music-my-pict) .My aim is to search all files inside the "My Documents" folder. This also includes searching all subdirectories such as My Music, My Pictures etc. Could anyone suggest some different code I can use or a solution to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you logged on as the "Test" user when you run that program?

Comment: No the program is behaving as it should. `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` should return `C:\Users\Test\Documents`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes. That's the only user on the computer.

Comment: @BoredomOverload Yes it does return that path but I guess something is wrong with the search algorithm. Specifically SearchOption.AllDirectories.

Comment: You cannot know how your directory's permission are set up, so your best bet is not to search all folders, but go folder by folder recursively yourself and stop going further with that folder if access is denied.

Comment: Can you open that folder in Windows Explorer, while being logged on as that user?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen No I can't. That's the thing, it's searching for a folder that doesn't exist.

Comment: @nemanja228 Thanks for the suggestion. I've considered doing that as a solution so I might as well work on it if my current code can't be fixed. However this SO thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830069/searching-for-file-in-directories-recursively/9830116) recommends using Directory.GetFiles which I'm doing right now.

Comment: `My Music` (localized) is in `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);`. The Documents folder is really not a good starting point for a blind enumeration of Directories and Files. You have already found the `AccessDenied` problem. You'll also find the `ReparsePoints` almost-infinite-loop problem.

Comment: GetFiles does not continue when you get exceptions when you do not have access to files/folders.  See my solution at following posting on how to continue after an exception : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681860/cannot-list-all-the-sub-directories-in-linux-using-c-sharp/53683353#53683353